# Group lines with similar slope and y-intercept

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

In python I am using hough lines to detect lines on an image. It is working pretty well to detect lines, but the [source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOqbs.png) is hand drawn producing many straight lines over each line segment.  I would like to combine lines with similar slope and y intercept to recreate the overall structure of image.
I know I can change the hough line parameters (threshold, min_length, max_gap,) to make longer straighter lines but I would like to keep the granular output of the hough line function and remake the structure with the outputted lines

Hough lines of the image looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgKQe.jpg)

My current output is a dict with start/end points of lines, slope and y-intercept:

```
{'slope': -2.0, 'start': (438, 317), 'yintercept': 167.0, 'end': (457, 279)}
{'slope': -8.0, 'start': (580, 414), 'yintercept': 1442.0, 'end': (582, 398)}
{'slope': -5.333333333333333, 'start': (438, 375), 'yintercept': 
{'slope': -1.5, 'start': (492, 215), 'yintercept': 142.5, 'end': (502, 200)}
{'slope': 0.0, 'start': (524, 316), 'yintercept': 152.0, 'end': (536, 316)}
{'slope': 3.0, 'start': (533, 238), 'yintercept': -232.0, 'end': (527, 220)}
{'slope': -1.9142857142857144, 'start': (450, 292), 'yintercept': 164.37142857142857, 'end': (485, 225)}
{'slope': 0.0, 'start': (467, 317), 'yintercept': 153.0, 'end': (523, 317)}
```

There are 40 lines in the original output but I would like to combine into just 6 lines.

My questions:

1. What is the best method to groupby both slope and y-intercept?
2. How do I group by line that are similar and not exact?

I am able to group by exact slope:

```
grouper = itemgetter("slope")
    result = []
    for key, grp in groupby(sorted(line_dict, key = grouper), grouper):
        result.append(list(grp))
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: plot your slopes and y-intercepts as points in a scatter chart.. then peruse [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) page to pick your favorite clustering algo. I personally have used DBSCAN on some particularly ugly data for my senior thesis a few years ago.

Comment: slope and intercept seem to me to be poor features, slope can 'blow up' to infinity.  
End Points, unit direction vectors seem to me to be the critical features, 'slope' similarity is the absolute value of the dot product of the unit direction vectors (assuming segment 'start, 'end' don't actually carry line connectivity/orientation information)

Comment: Thank you for these tips. I am working on using the unit direction vector with the DBSCAN method.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I am very close to getting the cluster I want, I asked a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406870/python-clustering-hough-lines)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  -

```
norm = np.linalg.norm(b, ord=2, axis=1) 
#b = array of start and end of lines 
# axis 1 = row
print(norm)
```

and check if norm is in range or below certain threshold