# Python- Clustering Hough lines

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am working to cluster probabilistic hough lines together using unit vectors.
The clustering changes every run though and is not quite right. I want to cluster the lines of [this image][2]. But I am getting this [clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozq7H.jpg) and it changes drastically every run though.
I know the probabilistic hough changes slightly every run but I would like the keep the merged lines pretty consistent. Is the problem with the way I am calculating unit-vector or DBSCAN or is there a better way to do clustering. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    line_dict = []
    # using hough lines thru skimage.transform- probabilistic_hough_line
    for line in lines:
        meta_lines = {}
        start_point, end_point = line

        # line equations and add line info to line dictionary
        meta_lines["start"] = start_point
        meta_lines["end"] = end_point
        distance = [end_point[0] - start_point[0], end_point[1] - start_point[1]]            
        norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
        direction = [distance[0] / norm, distance[1] / norm]
        meta_lines["unit-vector"] = direction
        line_dict.append(meta_lines)

    #clustering of lines using DBSCAN
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform([x["unit-vector"] for x in line_dict])
    db = DBSCAN(eps=0.2, min_samples=1).fit(X)
    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
    labels = db.labels_

    # Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)    
    clusters = [X[labels == i] for i in range(n_clusters_)]

    #cluster start/end poitns of lines
    for c in range(len(clusters)):
        for i in range(len(line_dict)):
            line_dict[i]["scale"] = X[i]
            if line_dict[i]["scale"] in clusters[c]:
                line_dict[i]["cluster"] = c

    line_dict.sort(key=itemgetter("cluster"))
    cluster_lines = []
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(line_dict, lambda item: item["cluster"]):
         cluster_lines.append([(i["start"], i["end"]) for i in group])

    merged_lines = []
    for i in cluster_lines:
        points = []
        for x in i:
            p0, p1 = x
            points.extend((p0, p1))

        # sort points and use min/max for endpoints of line
        k = sorted(points)
        merged_lines.append([k[0],k[-1]])
```

Edit:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlCxf.png) (I am low rep on stackoverflow so I can only post 2 images, removed the original one with the hough lines on image.
Hough line code:

```
from skimage.transform import probabilistic_hough_line
 #Img is grayscale image
    thresh = threshold_otsu(img)
    binary = img > thresh
    binary = np.invert(binary)
    skel = skeletonize(binary) # skeletonize image
    lines = probabilistic_hough_line(skel,
                                     threshold=5,
                                     line_length=10,
                                     line_gap=5)
```

Comment: Trucco and Verri's [Introductory techniques for 3D Computer Vision](https://smile.amazon.com/Introductory-Techniques-3-D-Computer-Vision/dp/0132611082?sa-no-redirect=1) has a section on this. [Here's the relevant pages](https://imgur.com/a/j5HMr). Might be helpful.

Comment: Also would you mind uploading your original image prior to Hough transform and also the code you used to do the Hough so others can get similar results as you to start from? Or perhaps copy/paste the Hough lines result so that someone can easily add it to an array. Lastly, is any other user input possible? This task is far easier with e.g. the number of vertices/intersection points, or the number of separate lines, or the number of distinct angles, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I read thought that section it  helps to conceptualize how I want to cluster lines now just need to find how to implement in code.

Comment: I edited post with original image and hough transform code. I am also using a corner detection method on image but the image is hand drawn detected corners are sometimes unreliable.